# Sum of Two Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> If $f(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1$ and $g(x)=x^3-x^2+x-1$ are in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then
>
> a) $\langle f(x)\rangle +\langle g(x)\rangle =\langle x^3+x\rangle$
>
> b) $\langle f(x)\rangle +\langle g(x)\rangle =\langle f(x)\cdot g(x)\rangle$
>
> c) $\langle f(x)\rangle +\langle g(x)\rangle =\langle x^2+1\rangle $
>
> d) $\langle f(x)\rangle +\langle g(x)\rangle =\langle x^4-1\rangle $

How to approach this problem?

For a) $1.f(x)-1.g(x)=2(x^2+1)=(x^3+x)(\frac{2}{x})$ but $\frac{2}{x}$ is not a polynomial, so a) is false.

Is this way correct ?

Comment: Recall Bezout's identity and note that $f(x)=(x^2+1)(x+1)$ and $g(x)=(x^2+1)(x-1)$.

Comment: $$\begin{align} \text{right: } & \langle f(x)\rangle \\ \text{wrong: } & <f(x)>  \end{align}$$

Comment: @ Michael Hardy: ok ! I understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only common divisor of $f$ and $g$ is $x^2+1$, which is irreducible over $Q[x]\subset R[x]$, then (by the Bézout's identity (why is it valid?)) there exist $a,b\in Q[x]$ such that $a.f+b.g=x^2+1$, that means $x^2+1\in \langle f\rangle+\langle g\rangle$, on the other hand, for every $a,b\in Q[x]$, $a.f+b.g=(x^2+1)(a(x+1)+b(x-1))\in \langle x^2+1 \rangle$. Thus $\langle f\rangle+\langle g\rangle =\langle x^2+1\rangle.$

For the first and last alternatives, you can immediatly conclude they are false after writing the following equivalent (why?) statements:

a) $\langle x+1\rangle+\langle x-1\rangle=\langle x\rangle$, it's false because $x+1\not \in \langle x\rangle$.

d) $\langle x+1\rangle+\langle x-1\rangle=\langle x^2-1\rangle$, again $x+1\not \in \langle x^2-1\rangle$.

And the remaining one:

b) $f\not \in \langle f.g\rangle$.

> How to approach this problem?

Look for common divisors and try to simplify the alternatives.

Comment: so c) is a correct one.. ?

Comment: Yeah, c) is the correct one.